# Conditionally define imported components in VueJs

Tags: vue.js

Lets say i have a parent component in VueJs with two versions of child component (A, B).
Is there a way to do something like this? Dynamically define component rather than using v-if and v-else?

```
<template>
    <Child />
</template>

<script>
import A from './components/A.vue';
import B from './components/B.vue';

export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  components: {
    Child: () => {
      if (renderA === true) {
        return A;
      } else {
        return B;
      }
    },
  },
  computed: {
    renderA() {
      return Math.random() < 0.5;
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `<component>` tag. [Vue Docs](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#component)

```html
<template>
    <component :is="toRender" />
</template>

<script>
import A from './components/A.vue';
import B from './components/B.vue';

export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  computed: {
    toRender() {
      return Math.random() < 0.5 ? A : B
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: May be better for toRender to be components and not strings, this way it's less ambiguous